# File Upload with Parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, post, file-upload

I'm trying to use C# and the .NET Framework 4.0 to make a program which can upload a local file along with some additional request parameters through an HTTP POST request.

Basically it would result in a request like this:

```
http:\\example.com\upload.html?file=<filedata goes here>&private=1&type=archive
```

It should be a POST request though not a GET request.

Does ASP.NET 4.0 provide any means of doing this?

Edit for clarity: I want to upload a local file to a server with my program, my program will not run **on** the server.

Comment: ASP.NET?.......http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/01/file-upload-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx

Comment: OK.  *Are you using ASP.NET?*  The above blog entry has a detailed description and sample code, using the ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: No I am not currently using ASP.NET

Comment: You're going to need something to process the POST request, so if you don't want to stand up an ASP.NET server, you will have to roll your own server of some sort.  Node.JS comes to mind.  Have a look here: http://ayende.com/blog/72705/node-cs and https://github.com/Rduerden/Node.cs

Comment: Are you trying to upload a file to an existing server or do you need to create a server app that allows users to upload a local file?

Comment: @Josh I want to upload to an existing server that I don't own.

Comment: Easy enough.  The answer by Stephen below is all you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [System.Net.HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class. Set the Method property to "POST" to use POST rather than GET. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data) seems to have it covered.